# Cross-platform flat-file data storage for ASP/PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, json, yaml

I'm starting a small project in ASP.Net/C# which will likely be ported in future to PHP and possibly other languages. The settings for this project are going to be the same across platforms, but can be modified by the user, so I'd like to store them in a flat-file, something like XML or JSON or YAML.

I'd prefer to avoid using external libraries. I want my app to basically be self-contained in one file.

What is the most universally accepted format for flat-files? For example, I know PHP5 can handle JSON without any extras, but in ASP.NET I need to install JSON.NET.

Is there any file that I can create a complex data structure in that's universally readable, without the need for external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated YAML, JSON, XML and SQLite* for this.

**YAML**

- Advantages: highly readable.
- Disadvantages: 
  Requires external libraries in both PHP and ASP.NET

**XML**

- Advantages: widely used, native support in ASP.NET
- Disadvantages: 
  Requires external libraries in PHP, easy to mess up by not closing a tag correctly, takes up more space than JSON and YAML, not very readable

**JSON**

- Advantages: small footprint, supported natively PHP
- Disadvantages: Requires external libraries in ASP.NET

**SQLite**

- Advantages: full database, SQL query support
- Disadvantages: Requires external libraries in both ASP.NET and PHP, can't be viewed without a third-party app

**Answer:**

Basically, JSON is the closest to what I want. While it's not natively supported in ASP.NET, JSON.NET is an excellent, well documented plugin and nuget makes it a snap to install on any project.

I would love to use YAML, as it's just so damn readable, but it requires libraries in both languages and they aren't very well documented at all.

* *The brief was for flat file storage. While SQLite isn't a flat file, it is a single file in which data is stored, so it's quite close to the brief*